# Error:(23, 20) Failed to resolve: com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:2.1

Tags: android

I want to use PhotoView for zooming in android 
https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView
but I'm getting the following error

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:2.1.3 '//zoom
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.2 '
}
```

root level **build.gradle**

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Make sure, You added this in your **root level**  **`build.gradle`** section.

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
```

After that, **`Clean-Rebuild-Run`**.

**Demo**

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        google()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: @AsadMirza show your root level `build.gradle`. Did you restart  IDE?

Comment: You should highlight your demo section :-)

Answer (score 0):

try to compile with previous dependency version like

```
implementation 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:2.0.0'
```

clean project and rebuild.